# Google BigQuery returns only partial table data with C# application using .net Client Library

Tags: google-bigquery, google-api-dotnet-client

I am trying to execute the query (Basic select statement with 10 fields). My table contains more than 500k rows. C# application returns the response with only 4260 rows. However Web UI returns all the records.

Why my code returns only partial data, What is the best way to select all the records and load into C# Data Table? If there is any code snippet it would be more helpful to me.

```
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using Google.Apis.Bigquery.v2;
using Google.Apis.Bigquery.v2.Data;
using System.Data;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

namespace GoogleBigQuery
{
    public class Class1
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Start Time: {0}", DateTime.Now.ToString());
                String serviceAccountEmail = "SERVICE ACCOUNT EMAIL";

                var certificate = new X509Certificate2(@"KeyFile.p12", "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

                ServiceAccountCredential credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(
                   new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail)
                   {
                       Scopes = new[] { BigqueryService.Scope.Bigquery, BigqueryService.Scope.BigqueryInsertdata, BigqueryService.Scope.CloudPlatform, BigqueryService.Scope.DevstorageFullControl }
                   }.FromCertificate(certificate));

                BigqueryService Service = new BigqueryService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
                {
                    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                    ApplicationName = "PROJECT NAME"
                });

                string query = "SELECT * FROM [publicdata:samples.shakespeare]";

                JobsResource j = Service.Jobs;

                QueryRequest qr = new QueryRequest();

                string ProjectID = "PROJECT ID";

                qr.Query = query;
                qr.MaxResults = Int32.MaxValue;
                qr.TimeoutMs = Int32.MaxValue;

                DataTable DT = new DataTable();
                int i = 0;

                QueryResponse response = j.Query(qr, ProjectID).Execute();

                string pageToken = null;

                if (response.JobComplete == true)
                {
                    if (response != null)
                    {
                        int colCount = response.Schema.Fields.Count;

                        if (DT == null)
                            DT = new DataTable();

                        if (DT.Columns.Count == 0)
                        {
                            foreach (var Column in response.Schema.Fields)
                            {
                                DT.Columns.Add(Column.Name);
                            }
                        }

                        pageToken = response.PageToken;

                        if (response.Rows != null)
                        {
                            foreach (TableRow row in response.Rows)
                            {
                                DataRow dr = DT.NewRow();

                                for (i = 0; i < colCount; i++)
                                {
                                    dr[i] = row.F[i].V;
                                }

                                DT.Rows.Add(dr);
                            }
                        }
                        Console.WriteLine("No of Records are Readed: {0} @ {1}", DT.Rows.Count.ToString(), DateTime.Now.ToString());

                        while (true)
                        {
                            int StartIndexForQuery = DT.Rows.Count;
                            Google.Apis.Bigquery.v2.JobsResource.GetQueryResultsRequest SubQR = Service.Jobs.GetQueryResults(response.JobReference.ProjectId, response.JobReference.JobId);
                            SubQR.StartIndex = (ulong)StartIndexForQuery;
                            //SubQR.MaxResults = Int32.MaxValue;
                            GetQueryResultsResponse QueryResultResponse = SubQR.Execute();

                            if (QueryResultResponse != null)
                            {
                                if (QueryResultResponse.Rows != null)
                                {
                                    foreach (TableRow row in QueryResultResponse.Rows)
                                    {
                                        DataRow dr = DT.NewRow();

                                        for (i = 0; i < colCount; i++)
                                        {
                                            dr[i] = row.F[i].V;
                                        }

                                        DT.Rows.Add(dr);
                                    }
                                }

                                Console.WriteLine("No of Records are Readed: {0} @ {1}", DT.Rows.Count.ToString(), DateTime.Now.ToString());

                                if (null == QueryResultResponse.PageToken)
                                {
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Response is null");
                    }
                }


                int TotalCount = 0;

                if (DT != null && DT.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    TotalCount = DT.Rows.Count;
                }
                else
                {
                    TotalCount = 0;
                }

                Console.WriteLine("End Time: {0}", DateTime.Now.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine("No. of records readed from google bigquery service: " + TotalCount.ToString());
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error Occurred: " + e.Message);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

In this Sample Query get the results from public data set, In table contains 164656 rows but response returns 85000 rows only for the first time, then query again to get the second set of results. (But not known this is the only solution to get all the results).

In this sample contains only 4 fields, even-though it does not return all rows, in my case table contains more than 15 fields, I get response of ~4000 rows out of ~10k rows, I need to query again and again to get the remaining results for selecting 1000 rows takes time up to 2 minutes in my methodology so I am expecting best way to select all the records within single response.

Comment: Please post the code that is not working.

Comment: Hi Mark, Code snippet added. Please have a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Answer from User #:Pentium10**

There is no way to run a query and select a large response in a single shot. You can either paginate the results, or if you can create a job to export to files, then use the files generated in your app. Exporting is free.

Step to run a large query and export results to files stored on GCS:

1) Set allowLargeResults to true in your job configuration. You must also specify a destination table with the allowLargeResults flag.

**Example:**

```
"configuration": 
  {
    "query": 
    {
      "allowLargeResults": true,
      "query": "select uid from [project:dataset.table]"
      "destinationTable": [project:dataset.table]

    }
  }
```

2) Now your data is in a destination table you set. You need to create a new job, and set the export property to be able to export the table to file(s). Exporting is free, but you need to have Google Cloud Storage activated to put the resulting files there.

3) In the end you download your large files from GCS.

It my turn to design the solution for better results.

Answer (score 1):

Hoping this might help someone. One could retrieve next set of paginated result using PageToken. Here is the sample code for how to use PageToken. Although, I liked the idea of exporting for free. Here, I write rows to flat file but you could add them to your DataTable. Obviously, it is a bad idea to keep large DataTable in memory though.

```
    public void ExecuteSQL(BigqueryService bqservice, String ProjectID)
    {
        string sSql = "SELECT r.Dealname, r.poolnumber, r.loanid FROM [MBS_Dataset.tblRemitData] R left join each [MBS_Dataset.tblOrigData] o on R.Dealname = o.Dealname and R.Poolnumber = o.Poolnumber and R.LoanID = o.LoanID Order by o.Dealname, o.poolnumber, o.loanid limit 100000";

        QueryRequest _r = new QueryRequest();
        _r.Query = sSql;
        QueryResponse _qr = bqservice.Jobs.Query(_r, ProjectID).Execute();

        string pageToken = null;
        if (_qr.JobComplete != true)
        {
            //job not finished yet! expecting more data
            while (true)
            {
                var resultReq = bqservice.Jobs.GetQueryResults(_qr.JobReference.ProjectId, _qr.JobReference.JobId);
                resultReq.PageToken = pageToken;
                var result = resultReq.Execute();

                if (result.JobComplete == true)
                {
                    WriteRows(result.Rows, result.Schema.Fields);
                    pageToken = result.PageToken;
                    if (pageToken == null)
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            List<string> _fieldNames = _qr.Schema.Fields.ToList().Select(x => x.Name).ToList();
            WriteRows(_qr.Rows, _qr.Schema.Fields);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The Web UI automatically [flattens](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/data#flatten) the data. This means that you see multiple rows for each nested field.

When you run the same query via the API, it won't be flattened, and you get fewer rows, as the nested fields are returned as objects. You should check if this is the case at you.

The other is that indeed you need to paginate through the results. [Paging through list results](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/data#paging) has this explained.

If you want to do only one job, than you should write your query ouput to a table, than export the table as JSON, and download the export from GCS.

Comment: It is not because of flattens the data. May be i want to paginate the results.  How pagination is suitable for larger table because my table contains more than 15 lakhs rows with 25 fields, Each Response took ~6 seconds for returning ~4500 rows, then how long it took for return 15 lakhs rows. Is that performance is good?  Eventhough for 1 lakh rows it took ~5 Minutes, i could not expect this from Google BigQuery? Is there is any working sample in .NET client library it would be helpful to me. i want to display report based on Query output, I could not imaging ~1h took retrieving data itself.

Comment: As you say running the query would take around 3-5 seconds. You should try doing an export job. Please also be aware this is big data technology, and not traditional databases where you have fast response time. Here you have decent response time even if your data is megabytes or petabytes. It's very fast compared to petabytes.

Comment: Hi Pentium, I would like to run not just Select * From Statement from the existing table, I want to perform some of the aggregation functions, The rows after aggregation is about ~3 Lakhs, i want to load that result into C# DataTable.

Comment: The approach is wrong here, as you cannot load 100 000 items in a DataTable, that is a wrong aproach, it will freeze your app, you don't have enough memory to hold so many objects.

Comment: My system has 16 GB RAM & 1 TB hard disk, this approach is working fine with SQL server 2008 R2. But only facing performance related issue in SQL, so that i have decided to move into big data analysis and working with Google BigQuery.

Comment: Google BigQuery really working very fast in Web UI, but unable to get the same results using API with that same time span, that's what i am struggling now.

Comment: @selvakumar - the Web UI uses the same API that you have access to. There shouldn't be any difference of speed when operating in or out the UI. If you want to check the API calls that the web UI is doing to replicate them on your code, you could use your browser networking console - to see and replicate the exact calls that the web ui does.

Comment: Google BigQuery .Net client library does not return all the records at single shot, it returns only ~10MB of data for each response, for getting entire results i need to paginate through using **PageToken**, but it takes 2 minutes for ~100K records. WebUI Query execution time is 12 seconds. But i am not able to get the same results in 12 seconds using C# code, that is my concern. It calculates faster i agree but not return full set to Response.

Comment: If anyone having a working sample for selecting large result set (~200K) using C# code with BigQuery, Kindly share with this post, it would be helpful for my POC project.

Comment: Note that the web UI reports query completion after receiving the first page of results.  It only pulls additional pages of results from the API as needed to paint them into the display.  I would second @Pentium10's suggestion to export the table to GCS and load it from there, as that will likely be more performant than repeatedly retrieving individual pages from the API.